# Throws "Java.lang.AssertionError: Unsupported type parameter" When we pass DriverManagerType browser in TESTNG

Tags: selenium

Thanks for providing the `webdrivermanager-3.7.1 Jar`.

I have written small Selenium Webdriver+TestNG program. I am using @Parameters({"browser","URL"}) in my code and pass DriverManagerType.

When I executed TestNG or this class,It throws `"java.lang.AssertionError: Unsupported type parameter :classio.github.bonigarcia.wdm.DriverManagerType".`

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Optional;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.DriverManagerType;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class testNewSeleniumManager {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters({"browser","URL"})
    public void lunchBrowser(@Optional("optional value") DriverManagerType browser,String URL) throws Throwable
    {
        WebDriverManager.getInstance(browser).setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
    }
    @Test
    public void URL1()
    {
        driver.get("https://dzone.com/articles/webdriver-manager-hassle-free-browser-binary-manag");
    }   
}
```

```
TrackStace:
java.lang.AssertionError: Unsupported type parameter : class io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.DriverManagerType
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.convertType(Parameters.java:246)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:165)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:355)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createConfigurationParameters(Parameters.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:199)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:641)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:609)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
```

Comment: Perhaps you are passing type String `browser` to type `DriverManagerType`? Instead read the browser as type String in your method and inside the method convert it into type `DriverManagerType`

Comment: TestNG.xml file======<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
  <parameter name="URL" value="https://in.via.com/bus-tickets"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="SeleniumWebManager.SeleniumWebManager.testNewSeleniumManager"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->